# Problems using xml validation with xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

It is the first time i'm using xsd to validate an xml document in java and I really can't seem to get this to work.

Well, first of all here is my xml document structure, Employees.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:Employees xmlns:x="urn:Employees">
  <Employee id="1">
    <name>Some Guy</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
  </Employee>
  <Employee id="2">
    <name>Some lady</name>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <role>CEO</role>
  </Employee>
</x:Employees>
```

And here is my xsd file structure, EmployeesXmlSchema.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:x="urn:Employees" targetNamespace="urn:Employees">

<xsd:element name="Employees" type="x:Employees"/>
<xsd:complexType name="Employees">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Employee" type="x:Employee" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Employee">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="gender" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="role" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And here is the java code, trying to validate the xml document:

```
try {
            String language = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
            schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

            // Parse the XML document to DOM Document, and then validate it
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(source);

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }
```

The error I am getting is a SAXParseException and says:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'Employee'. One of
>   '{"urn:Employees":Employee}' is expected.

I really hope someone can explain to me why this is going wrong.

Any help will be grreatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should correct your XML:

```
<Employees xmlns="urn:Employees" id="1">
    <name>Some Guy</name>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <role>Java Developer</role>
</Employees>
```

or correct your XSD:

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:x="urn:Employees" targetNamespace="urn:Employees">

<xsd:element name="Employees" type="x:Employees"/>
<xsd:complexType name="Employees">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Employee" type="x:Employee" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Employee">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="gender" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="role" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Second, you should enable support for XML namespaces:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am getting another error now though. I have updated my code and error message in the question. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Never mind @Alex. I found this site for generating xsd from xml and opposite: http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html. I'll accept your answer anyways, as it helped me on the way nevertheless. Thank you :)